# How should the topic of frequency domain be taught?

Tags: education

This is a soft question but I think it's a real fact.The Frequency domain has made revolution in the field of Mathematics,  Digital Signal and image Processing. Some of concepts which are very difficult to analyse in spatial or time domain can be very easily understood in the frequency domain using the theorems like Fourier transform & series, wavelets ,Laplace transform etc.

Well,I am doing under graduation in 4 years Electronics and Telecommunication Engineering .We have semester pattern system (2 semesters in 1 year).In the 3rd semester, We have subject named "Signals and Systems" under which the above topic is covered.

But my experience is that  when it is being taught in the academic curriculum or course, it is not given as much importance as it has to be. Most of the teachers or professors don't know how teach this topic. They teach with the help of readymade PowerPoint presentations (e.g. for Laplace transform, single PPT which is mostly downloaded  from internet )and sometimes they take chalk in their hand .So the students like us get hardly any knowledge about the frequency domain in academic course compared to discussions in the forum like the very useful http://www.DSP.stackexchange.com . and http://www.math.stackexchange.com

So I am requesting the scholars, eminent professors and researchers to give some guidelines or explanation so that students as well as teachers get to know how frequency domain topic should be studied and taught in the academic curriculum. And all of us would study this topic with interest.

Comment: Is this a question or a request?

Comment: Numerically evaluating transforms, applying transfer functions, etc. on a computer helped me. Basically seeing that it actually *works* is usually nice.

Comment: I'd post this on the maths educators site it's an interesting question.

Comment: @Rammus sir ,you can consider it as both question and request. I told what happens in our education system. But I think the way the people on this forum were being taught must be totally different as I could judge from answers given for any question by the people

Comment: @Karl - It was posted there about a week ago: http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/8102/how-should-the-topic-of-frequency-domain-be-taught-in-an-academic-course.

Comment: @Karl sir ,but I couldn't get any answer there yet.

Comment: Sorry, must have missed it.

Comment: @Karl - update: just checked there and noticed that there is now a message stating "This question was voluntarily removed by its author."